# jQuery :empty not working in Jade

Tags: jquery, pug

I have a div on my page for information messages, but I want it to not be visible if it's empty.
I'm using the following jQuery script in my layout file but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting an empty blue box, but I want it to be hidden unless there's content inside it.

```
script(type='text/javascript')
    $('#info:empty').hide();
```

The actual Jade file just has:

```
extends layout

block head
    title Test page

block content
    if (message)
        #info= message
```

I have another working jQuery script that fades the whole div out so I don't think it's a problem with the layout file, but here it is anyway:

```
head
    link(href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
    link(href="/stylesheets/style.css", type="text/css", rel="stylesheet")
    script(type='text/javascript', src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js");
    script(type='text/javascript')
        $(document).ready(function(){
           setTimeout(function(){
          $("#info").fadeOut("slow", function () {
          $("#info").remove();
              });

        }, 2000);
         });
    script(type='text/javascript')
        $('#info:empty').hide();
    meta(http-equiv='Content-Type', content='text/html; charset=utf-8')
    block head

body
    block content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move it inside the document).ready that way it will fire.

```
    script(type='text/javascript')
        $(document).ready(function(){
           setTimeout(function(){
          $("#info").fadeOut("slow", function () {
          $("#info").remove();
              });

        }, 2000);
         $('#info:empty').hide();
        });
```